# 413 Request Entity Too Large nginx server in laravel while uploading video file

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, file-upload

I am trying to upload video files of around 150MB via my project.

and I get the error **413 Request Entity Too Large nginx** every-time I try

as per some of the articles I found I changed my nginx.conf in aws server as below

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Then add a line in the http section

```
http {
    client_max_body_size 500M;
}

sudo system restart nginx
```

then for php location

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini
```

couldn't find this file but I have updated
post_max_size and upload size to 500M in php.ini and it's updated when I check `phpinfo();` in my project

```
memory_limit = 500M 
post_max_size = 500M  
upload_max_filesize = 500M
```

restarted nginx
stopped & restarted as well

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Still couldn't find a solution.
please help me out with it

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Can you try `sudo service php7.4-fpm restart` and try uploading again?

Comment: do you have other nginx config files? maybe configuration for ingress paths overrides the generic you're changing. Additional config files should be at /etc/nginx/sites-available

Comment: @Andrea no I don't have any external nginx config files

Comment: @AnupPatel can you describe the "infrastructure"? Is anything on your local machine or you have docker/kubernetes/anything-else in the middle?

Comment: @Andrea this project is built using Laravel Framework and hosted on AWS that's it